# How can I watch the output that was filtered with grep?

Tags: command-line, grep, gsettings, watch-command

I want to watch the changes of the output

```
gsettings list-recursively|grep text-scal
```

which is

```
org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0  
com.canonical.Unity.Interface text-scale-factor 1.0
```

but if I try to watch it with

```
watch gsettings list-recursively|grep text-scal
```

I get no output, because the pipe seems to be the problem.

How can I still watch the changes?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193270/how-to-perform-the-watch-command-onto-expression-with-pipes may be helpful

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You need to enclose the piped command in quotes as follows:

```
watch -n 2 'gsettings list-recursively|grep text-scal'
```

This will execute the command `gsettings list-recursively|grep text-scal` and `watch` it every two seconds. Note that the time interval is in seconds.

Refer to [watch's manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) for more.

Comment: for me this worked `watch 'ifconfig enp0s26u1u6 | grep "RX packet"'`